# How about Decode Base64 Algorithm

Tags: cryptography, base64, decode

Anyone know how Base64 decoding Algorithm, as information in the internet many article, journal, and book explain how to encoding base64 algorithm But the decoding Base64 not explained.So my question is how to decode Base4 algorithm?

Thank you,
Hope Your Answer

Answer (score 5):

Basically you take one character at the time and convert it to the bits that it represents. So if you find an `A` character it would translate into `000000` and the `/` character translates into `111111`. Then you concatenate the bits. So you get `000000 | 111111`. This however won't fit into a byte, you have to split up and shift the result to get `00000011` and `1111xxxx` where `xxxx` is not known yet

Of course, you may only be able to do this using bytes in a high performance implementation, so you have two spurious bits for each character (separated by a space from the bits that actually mean something).

```
((00 000000 << 2) & 11111100) | ((00 111111 >> 4) & 00000011) -> 00000011
((00 111111 << 4) & 11110000) | ???????? -> 1111xxxx
...
```

First with the shift operator `<<` you put the bits in place. Then with the binary AND operator `&` you single out those bits you want and then you use the binary OR `|` operator you assemble the bits of the two characters.

Now after 4 characters you will have 3 full bytes. It may however be that your result is not a multiple of three. In that case you have either two or three characters possibly followed by padding (`=`) at the end. One character is not possible as that would suggest an incomplete byte with only the highest bits set. In that case you should simply ignore the last spurious bits encoded by the last character.

Personally I like to use a state machine to do the decoding. I've already created a couple of base 64 streams that use a state machine in Java. It may be useful to only decode once you have 4 characters (3 full bytes) until you are at the end of the base 64 encoding.